# springboot + angular2 deployment

Tags: java, angular, spring-boot

I am trying to deploy my spring boot with angular 2 code to a war package

My springboot code contains JWT Spring security,

1. The problem is when I integrate and run in tomcat server. I am getting:

> Whitelabel Error Page This application has no explicit mapping for
>   /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.
>
> Thu Mar 01 18:26:53 IST 2018 There was an unexpected error (type=Not
>   Found, status=404). No message available

2. But if i remove my spring security and integrate both together then it is working fine.

I don't know what is the problem with spring JWT security, So please, if anybody knows this issue, help me out

**Web Security:**

```
package com.boot.hms.security;

import org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.http.HttpMethod;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.security.config.http.SessionCreationPolicy;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.CrossOrigin;
import org.springframework.web.cors.CorsConfiguration;
import org.springframework.web.cors.CorsConfigurationSource;
import org.springframework.web.cors.UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource;
import org.springframework.web.filter.CorsFilter;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.CorsRegistry;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurer;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurerAdapter;
@CrossOrigin
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurity extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    private UserDetailsService userDetailsService;
    private BCryptPasswordEncoder bCryptPasswordEncoder;

    public WebSecurity(UserDetailsService userDetailsService, BCryptPasswordEncoder bCryptPasswordEncoder) {
        this.userDetailsService = userDetailsService;
        this.bCryptPasswordEncoder = bCryptPasswordEncoder;
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        AuthenticationFilter authenticationFilter = new AuthenticationFilter(authenticationManager());
        authenticationFilter.setFilterProcessesUrl("/hms/auth");

        http .cors().and().csrf().disable().authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/hms/fetchmeta/*", "/hms/registration/*").permitAll()
        .anyRequest().authenticated().and().addFilter(authenticationFilter)
                .addFilter(new AuthorizationFilter(authenticationManager()))
                // this disables session creation on Spring Security
                .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);


        System.out.println("<....Web Security......>");
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService).passwordEncoder(bCryptPasswordEncoder);
    }   

    @Bean
        CorsConfigurationSource corsConfigurationSource() {
            final UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
            source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", new CorsConfiguration().applyPermitDefaultValues());
            return source;
        } 

}
```

**POM XML:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>hms</artifactId>
    <version>1</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <name>version</name>

    <description>Hospital Management System</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.10.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> 
    </parent>


    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <start-class>com.programmer.gate.HmsApplication</start-class>
    </properties>



    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-mail</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>         
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
            <artifactId>jjwt</artifactId>
            <version>0.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jersey</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                  <webResources>
                    <resource>
                      <directory>D:\hmsDeployment\dist</directory>
                    </resource>
                  </webResources>
                </configuration>
              </plugin>

        </plugins>
    </build>


</project>
```

**Main class:**

```
package com.boot.hms;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceTransactionManagerAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder;
import org.springframework.boot.web.support.SpringBootServletInitializer;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Import;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.CrossOrigin;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.CorsRegistry;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurer;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurerAdapter;

import com.boot.hms.security.WebSecurity;

@CrossOrigin
@Import(WebSecurity.class)
@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan(basePackages="com.boot.hms")
public class HmsApplication extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

     @Override
        protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
            return application.sources(HmsApplication.class);
        }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(HmsApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    public BCryptPasswordEncoder bCryptPasswordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }   

}
```

**Property file:**

```
#Database
spring.datasource.url= jdbc:mysql://192.168.12.112:3306/hms
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=root

#Server
#server.contextPath=/hms
#server.port = 8080
#JPA
spring.jpa.show-sql = true
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto = update
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
spring.autoconfigure.exclude=SecurityAutoConfiguration
#security.user.name=admin
#security.user.password=admin
security.basic.enabled=false
spring.jackson.serialization.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS=false
spring.jackson.deserialization.accept-empty-string-as-null-object=true
```

Comment: @lealceldeiro Hi, see now i am actually getting error like this::::::::::                    
    Whitelabel Error Page
This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.

Fri Mar 02 13:38:44 IST 2018
There was an unexpected error (type=Forbidden, status=403).
Access Denied

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solution**

You are probably seeing this error because of your custom security configuration class (`WebSecurity`)

You did not explicitly declared a "Free for all" rule for the base url, `/` (were the Angular app will live!). Here I am assuming the base url is `/`, if not adapt this answer to be used with your base real url.

So, in your **`WebSecurity`** add the mentioned rule by changing this:

```
 //...omitted code for brevity
 http.cors().and().csrf().disable().authorizeRequests()
    .antMatchers("/hms/fetchmeta/*", "/hms/registration/*").permitAll()
//...omitted code for brevity
```

to

```
 //...omitted code for brevity
 http.cors().and().csrf().disable().authorizeRequests()
    .antMatchers("/hms/fetchmeta/*", "/hms/registration/*", "/") // <--Notice here the base url added to the "free for all" rule!
    .permitAll()
//...omitted code for brevity
```

But ... **Why this error happen?!**

Well, as you commented, the explicit error is

> Whitelabel Error Page This application has no explicit mapping for
>   /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback. Fri Mar 02 13:38:44 IST
>   2018 There was an unexpected error (type=Forbidden, status=403).
>   Access Denied

This mean when you try to access the Angular app (located from the server point of view at the base url, `/`, for instance), the server detect that you're not logged in, so it throws a [403 Forbidden](https://httpstatuses.com/403). This would normally be shown in an error page in a Spring Boot application... and since you do not have a mapping for this route, `/error`, (neither you have the file under `src/main/resources/static/error/403.html` which would normally show this error), then you see this "fallback" message you showed me.

**Recommendation**

Since now the base url `/` is free for all, your services (provided by Spring Boot) should be prefixed with something like `/api` or any similar in order to prevent free access to them.

**Reference**

If you want to have a reference, check this [Security Config](https://github.com/lealceldeiro/gms/blob/master/server/src/main/java/com/gms/config/security/SecurityConfig.java), which does exactly what you're trying to do (it belongs to a project which deploy a *Spring Boot + Angular packed as war* project)

Comment: Thank you so much for your clarification, I am doing this deployment for more than a week. This is really helpful.